# Function that sends $(0, 0, z) , (0, y, 0)$ and $(x, 0,0)$ to $0$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I need to find a function that sends $(0, 0, z) , (0, y, 0)$ and $(x, 0,0)$ to $0$.

I am working in the real numbers and in order to find an element in the radical of my ideal I need a function of this form.

All I can figure out is that it should be of the form where one variable of $x, y$ and $z$ should always be multiplied by another, i.e $xy$. But I need a function that isn't a linear combination of $xy + xz +yz$ and $xyz$.

Comment: $x^2y + x^2z +y^2z$?

Comment: How about $f(x,y,z)\equiv 0$? I suppose it is a (trivial) linear combination of the form you don't want, though.

Comment: How about $\sin(x)\sin(y)\sin(z) $

Comment: $x(e^y-1)+y(e^z-1)+z(e^x-1)$

Comment: My issue is that a power of this function should be a linear combination of $xy + xz +yz$ and $xyz$ so I'm struggling to find one that satisfies this as well.

Comment: What about the discriminant? $$f(x,y,z)=(x-z)^2 (x-y)^2 (z-y)^2 $$

Answer (score 0):

Use $\;f(x,y,z) := axy+bxz+cyz$ with $a,b,c\;$ all different constants. It satisfies the equation$f(0,0,z) = f(0,y,0) = f(x,0,0) = 0$ and isn't a linear combination of $xy+xz+yz$ and $xyz$.